# Can someone explain what "reopen invalidated" means in a Question timeline?

Tags: support, review-queues, vote-to-reopen, timeline

I am trying to understand the timeline for this question:

[How can I generate 2 clocks in testbench with systemverilog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19524021/197758)

The question is currently closed.  I can see from the timeline that it was originally closed about 6 years ago (2013-oct-23): "close completed".

Later that day, it looks like it was reopened: "reopen completed".

Finally, a few weeks ago (2020-apr-27), it looks like it was closed again: "reopen **invalidated**".  Can someone explain why that happened?

Is my understanding correct that the question was really reopened for several years?

I did cast a reopen vote recently, hoping to reopen the question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On October 23, 2013, you cast a reopen vote on that question. This put it into the reopen review queue. The final outcome was a split decision: 3 to leave closed, and 3 to reopen. That resulted in no action being taken, but [the review was marked as "completed"](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3196867).

On April 22, 2020, you cast another vote to reopen. This put the question again into [the reopen review queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/25930275), but no other reviewers ever took action, so 5 days later (April 27, 2020), your reopen vote "aged away" and the review queue item was "invalidated" (i.e., canceled without being completed, due to inactivity).

(Moderators see a bit more detailed information in the timeline than normal users can see. For example, we can see individual close and/or reopen votes, when they were cast, and which user(s) cast them. However, nearly all of what I've mentioned here is publicly visible by looking at the review items and piecing together the timeline of events.)

The question was never reopened since the time that it was closed. This is even more obvious from [the question's revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/19524021/revisions). A gray banner shows actual close and reopen events (not review tasks). Note that this question has only ever been closed, and never reopened.

I've taken a critical look at the question, and I agree with you that it is suitable for reopening it. Being a moderator, I've cast a binding vote, which has resulted in it now being reopened.